# Создание класса двумерной матрицы c#

Tags: c#, ооп, матрицы, наследование

Нужно создать класс двумерной матрицы. При запуске выдает ошибку. В отладчике видно, что размер матрицы он видит но при этом самой матрицы как будто бы нет

```
using System;

namespace lab9var4
{
    // Создаем класс матрица
    class Matrix
    {
        // Создаем поля класса матрица. Т.к. нужно продемонстрировать наследование, модификатор доступа - protected
        protected int n { get; set; }
        protected int m { get; set; }
        protected int[,] a { get; set; }
        // Создаем конструктор класса матрица с параметрами: строка , столбец
        public Matrix(int n, int m, int[,]a)
        {
            //Указываем кл. словом this параметрам на поля класса
            this.n = n;
            this.m = m;
            // Инициализируем параметры - строку и столбец для матрицы a
            // Выделяем память для матрицы указывая this`ом параметрам на поля класса n - строка/ m - столбец
            a = new int[n, m];
            this.a[this.n, this.m] = a[n,m];
        }
        // Создаем ввод размера матрицы с клавиатуры
        public Matrix()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите размер строки");
            n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите размер столбца");
            m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        // Создаем метод для заполнения матрицы случайными числами от 0 до 9, что бы числа не были громоздкими
        public void rand()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int w = 0; w < m; i++)
                {
                    a[i, w] = rnd.Next(0,9);
                }
            }
        }
        // Создаем метод для печати матрицы в консоль
        public void print()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int w = 0; w < m; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(a[i, w]+"\t");
                }
            }
        }
        // Создаем метод для нахождения суммы элементов матрицы
        public int sum()
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int w = 0; w < m; i++)
                {
                    sum += a[i, w];
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }
        // Создаем метод для нахождения максимального элемента матрицы
        public int maxItem()
        {
            int maxItem = a[0,0];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int w = 0; w < m; i++)
                {
                    if (maxItem < a[i,w])
                    {
                        maxItem = a[i, w];
                    }
                }
            }
            return maxItem;
        }
    }
```

Создаем дочерний класс квадратной матрицы sqMatrix. P.S. sq это square - квадрат.

```
class sqMatrix:Matrix
{
    // Создаем поля класса производного от Matrix
    public int n { get; set; }
    public int[,] a { get; set; }
    // Создаем конструктор в котором будет только 1 параметр - размер кв. матрицы
    public sqMatrix(int n)
    {
        this.n = n;
        a = new int[this.n, this.n];
    }
    // Создаем ввод размера матрицы с клавиатуры
    public sqMatrix()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите размер квадратной матрицы");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    // Создаем метод по нахождению суммы диагональных элементов
    public int diagItemSum()
    {
        // count - элемент по счету, sum - сумма элементов
        int count = 0,sum = 0 ;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < n; i++)
            {
                // Элемент будет на главной диагонали при i == w
                // На побочной, если номер элемента будет равен сумме его индексов
                // Т.к. мы считаем с нуля то если i+w=count, a[i,w] - элемент побочной диагонали
                if (((i+=w)==count)||(i==w))
                {
                    sum += a[i, w];
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    // Создаем метод по проверки матрицы - является ли она симметричной
    // Матрица является симметричной если элементы по обоим сторонам гл. диагонали равны друг другу
    public bool symmMatrix()
    {
        // В count мы подсчитываем кол-во равных элементов
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < n; w++)
            {
                // Если элемент не находится на главной диагонали i!=w и элемент равен себе же при
                // [i, w] = > [w, i] изменении строки на столбец, count увеличивается
                if ((i != w) && a[i, w] == a[w,i])
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        // Теперь, если матрица симметрична: (ее размер * ее размер) - (количество элементов на гл. диагонали)
        // это все остальные элементы матрицы которые мы сравниваем с count и выводим в зависимости от этого результат
        if (count == ((n * n) - n))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Класс Program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Создаем обьект матрицы 
        Matrix a = new Matrix();
        a.rand();
        a.print();
        Console.WriteLine("Сумма элементов " + a.sum());
        Console.WriteLine("Максимальный элемент " + a.maxItem());
        sqMatrix b = new sqMatrix();
        b.print();
        Console.WriteLine("Сумма диагональных элементов " + b.diagItemSum());
        Console.WriteLine("Является ли матрица симметричной " + b.symmMatrix());
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте. Код необходимо оформлять с помощью текста, отформатировав его с помощью комбинации Ctrl+K. Это поможет ускорить ответ участников сообщества на ваш вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью соответствующей кнопки ("Править")

Comment: Так это вроде к полю обращение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не инициализирован массив. В конструкторе без параметров инициализации массива нет. Только ввод размерности

```
    // Создаем ввод размера матрицы с клавиатуры
    public Matrix()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите размер строки");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите размер столбца");
        m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        a = new int[n, m]; // добавить эту строку
    }
```

И ещё, думаю, тут опечатка

```
void Rand()
{
  ...
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int w = 0; w < m; w++) // было i++
      ...
}
```

И это, совет: не `m`, `n`, `i`, `w`, а `rowCount`, `columnCount`, `rowIndex`, `columnIndex`. Не `a`, а `array`

Comment: Обычно так и пишу, просто сейчас делаю лаб. работу другому человеку. За опечатку спасибо, но если бы была проблема в ней, я бы пофиксил. До опечатки не доходит потому что он видит что поле пустое

Comment: @AllTP кроме опечатки, как написано в ответе, нужно инициализацию массива добавить

Comment: Да, спасибо помогло. А не могли бы вы подсказать, возможно ли в данной реализации отключить вызов конструктора базового класса при создании обьекта дочернего класса, потому что он инициализирует размер матрицы по новому, а нужно что бы было только через поле n в дочернем классе? (к самому вопросу прикрепил поясняющее фото)

Comment: @AllTP я могу ответить, если подождёте

Comment: @AllTP, не совсем понимаю, чего Вы добиваетесь. Квадрат - точно такой же прямоугольник. В смысле, квадратная матрица - всё та же двумерная матрица. Зачем её лишать функционала двумерной матрицы? Тут, как мне видится, проще будет наоборот дёрнуть базовый конструктор. Тот, что принимает длину и ширину массива

Comment: @iKuzmychov Да, конечно. Я наверное по другому попробую объяснить, что я имею ввиду. Когда объявляется экземпляр квадратной матрицы, вызывается конструктор базового класса - произвольной матрицы. И вместо того что бы просто вышло сообщение из дочернего класса  - "Введите размер матрицы"  инициализируются сначала длина и ширина из базового класса, и они здесь явно лишние, там в скриншоте видно, что это как костыль выглядит

Comment: @AllTP я закончил писать ответ

Answer (score 4):

@AnatolyBelanov уже дал абсолютно верный ответ, но я хочу "нырнуть глубже" и поговорить в целом о написаном коде.

## Обо всём и по делу

Для начала, хочу поговорить о логических и не только ошибках, найденных, проходясь глазами по коду.

#### Фрагмент #1

У класса `Matrix` есть такой конструкор (комментарии опущены):

```
public Matrix(int n, int m, int[,] a)
{
    this.n = n;
    this.m = m;
    a = new int[n, m];
    this.a[this.n, this.m] = a[n, m];
}
```

Для чего существует параметр `int[,] a`? Этот аргумент является излишним и ненужным. Помимо прочего, в строке `this.a[this.n, this.m] = a[n, m];` вы присваеваете элемент с индексами `[n, m]` массива `a` элементу с индексами `[n, m]` массива `this.a`. Вы же, скорее всего, хотели присвоить массив. Код следует переписать так:

```
public Matrix(int n, int m)
{
    this.n = n;
    this.m = m;
    this.a = new int[n, m];
}
```

Если же по задумке это что-то, по-типу, конструктора копирования, то излишнимим являются `n` и `m`. В таком случае, код приобретает следующий вид:

```
public Matrix(int[,] a)
{
    this.a = a;
    this.n = a.GetLength(0);
    this.m = a.GetLength(1);
}
```

#### Фрагмент #2

В классе `Matrix` есть следующий метод:

```
// Создаем метод для заполнения матрицы случайными числами от 0 до 9, что бы числа не были громоздкими
public void rand()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < m; i++)
        {
            a[i, w] = rnd.Next(0, 9);
        }
    }
}
```

Тут можно отметить, как минимум, 2 важных момента (остальные позволю себе опустить):

1. Как указал @AnatolyBelanov, у вас опечатка в строке `for (int w = 0; w < m; i++)`, тут должно быть `w++`. Причём эта опечатка "из уст в уста" перешла из метода `rand()` во все остальные.
2. В комментарии вы указали, что заполняете матрицу `случайными числами от 0 до 9`, однако это не так: метод `Next` класса `Random` не включает верхнюю границу, в итоге максимальное число - 8.

#### Фрагмент #3

В классе `sqMatrix` есть следующий метод:

```
// Создаем метод по нахождению суммы диагональных элементов
public int diagItemSum()
{
    // count - элемент по счету, sum - сумма элементов
    int count = 0, sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < n; i++)
        {
            // Элемент будет на главной диагонали при i == w
            // На побочной, если номер элемента будет равен сумме его индексов
            // Т.к. мы считаем с нуля то если i+w=count, a[i,w] - элемент побочной диагонали
            if (((i += w) == count) || (i == w))
            {
                sum += a[i, w];
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Про `w++` уже было сказанно, так что это пропустим.

Первое, что меня смущает в этом методе, - это строчка с уловием: `((i += w) == count) || (i == w)`. Почему там `i += w`? Или это опечатка, или какой-то сложный алгоритм.

Второе - переменная `count`, которая нужна для... чего? Возможно, для отладки? Но для этого лучше подойдёт отладчик.

Ну и помимо того, этот код можно упростить, да ещё и оптимизировав:

```
public int diagItemSum()
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++, j++)
        sum += a[i, j] + a[i, n - j - 1]; // суммируем элемент главной и побочной диагоналей

    if (n % 2 == 1) // если размер непарный
        sum -= a[n / 2, n / 2]; // то мы должны вычесть центральный элемент, потому что мы просуммировали его дважды

    return sum;
}
```

## Распределение ответственности

Существует такое понятие (один из принципов SOLID), как распределение ответсвенности. В двух словах, это значит то, что каждый объект/метод должен делать только то, для чего он предназначен; делать только одно логическое действие. Под этим подразумевается, к примеру, то, что метод рассчёта не должен выводить ничего в консоль, ведь его задача лишь выполнить рассчёт. Этот принцип помогает также повысить возможность переиспользования написанного кода.

Относительно ваше кода этот принцип следует применить для класса `Matrix` (и аналогично для класса `sqMatrix`). В этом классе существует такой конструктор (да ещё и по-умолчанию):

```
public Matrix()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите размер строки");
    n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Введите размер столбца");
    m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Тут не важно, правильно ли работает этот метод (как указал AnatolyBelanov, тут нехватает `a = new int[n ,m]`). Суть в следующем: конструктор - это такая "штука", которая предназначена для инициализации объекта. В идеальном случае, единственное, что должен делать контруктор - инициализировать поля и свойства переданными аргументами. Допустимо и более сложное поведение, но конструктор нужен для инициализации. Вывод же и считывание данных с консоли это то, что никак не относится к конструктору и должно быть вынесено в отдельный метод (лучше всего вне класса `Matrix`).

## Наследование

Из написанного кода, я сделал вывод, что вы не до конца понимаете механизм наследования, по-этому, хочу немного прояснить.

#### Основное

Начнём с того, что наследуемый класс наследует все нестатические не приватные методы, поля и свойства. Допусти у нас есть классы `ClassA` и `ClassB`:

```
public class ClassA
{
  public int Property1 { get; }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
   public void ExampleMethod()
   {
       Property1++; // так как ClassB унаследован от ClassA, то свойство Property1 также унаследовано, и мы в любом месте можем к нему обращаться
   }
}
```

#### Перекрытие

Когда же вы, в унаследованном классе, пишите метод/поле/свойство, которые уже существуют в базовом, то вы их перекрываете. Все детали не так просто объянить, но, вкратце, вы "забываете" про унаследованный метод/поле/свойство и работаете с новосозданным. Это значит, что все "операции" базового класса, которые используют это метод/поле/свойство не будут знать о новом перекрывающем значении.

Пример:

```
public class ClassA
{
  public int Property1 { get; set; } = 5;

  public void PrintProperty1() => Console.WriteLine(Property1);
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
   public int Property1 { get; set; } = 8; // перекрывает базовый Property1

   // public void PrintProperty1() - унаследован
}
```

Использование и результат:

```
var b = new ClassB();
b.PrintProperty(); // будет выведено "5"
```

#### Конструкторы

Констуктор унаследованного класса **обязан** вызвать один из конструктор базового. Если у базового класса есть конструктор "по-умолчанию" (то есть, без аргументов), то неявно будет вызван он:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA() => Console.WriteLine("Конструктор А");
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    // неявно вызывает base()
    public ClassB() => Console.WriteLine("Конструктор B");
}
```

Использование и результат:

```
var b = new ClassB();

// Вывод:
//     Конструктор А
//     Конструктор B
```

Это причина, по которой, у вас конструкторы класса `sqMatrix` вызывают конструктор `Matrix()`.

Какой конструктор вызывать можно указать явно, что применимо в вашем коде:

```
class sqMatrix : Matrix
{
    // вызываем базовый конструктор с нужными параметрами
    public sqMatrix(int n) : base(n, n, new int[n, n]) { }

    // в идеале, после рефакторинга, должно быть так:
    // public SquareMatrix(int size) : base(size, size) { }
}
```

## Стиль кода

У языка C# существует [конвенция именования](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions), которая говорит о том: что, как и когда должно именоваться.

Самый простой и яркий пример правил именования - это правило именование всех классов и методов с Большой буквы.

```
Matrix.rand() -> Matrix.Rand()
sqMatrix      -> SqMatrix
...
```

Второе несложное правило (возможно, оно даже является внегласным) - называть свойства, методы, классы и т.д. в соответсвии с их смыслом:

```
n -> Height или RowsCount
m -> Widht или ColumnsCount
a -> Matrix или BaseMatrix
...
```

Также, не стоит применять сокращения, которые не являются общепринятыми и/или, когда они не имеют смысла:

```
sqMatrix -> SquareMatrix
rnd      -> random
```

Есть ещё много различных правил, с которыми вы можете ознакомится на [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions), как будет время.

## Комментарии

Комментарии это полезная вещь, но как и во всём, желательно придерживаться золотой середины: добавлять только там, где это и вправду необходимо. Излишние комментарии только мешают.

Нет, особо, никакого смысла в комментариях, по типу:

```
// Создаем класс матрица
class Matrix { ... }

// Указываем кл. словом this параметрам на поля класса
this.n = n;
```

Кроме того, если правильно именовать переменные и методы, то многие вещи и не нужно объяснять в комментариях. К примеру, если бы `n` называлось `Height` или `RowsCount`, то было бы очевидно, что переменная обозначет "высоту"/количество строк матрицы.

Также, хорошим тоном комментирования методов и классов, считается исользование [`<summary>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/documentation-comments). Такие комментарии могут отображаться просто при наведении курсора на соответсвующий метод, иметь подсветку, ссылки и прочее.

Comment: Благодарю вас, все по полочкам разложили мне. Теперь могу сделать вывод о преподавателе, составленных им лабораторным работам и о заявленных им требованиях

Comment: @AllTP ну в лабораторных работах бывают вещи нелогичные и, часто, задания далёкие от реальности и практичности, но в целом, к ним применимо всё тоже самое, что и к настоящему програмному продукту